# Sort RSS items by date in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, rss

I am combining multiple items into one RSS file iterating them like so:

```
# create RSS
atom = RSS::Maker.make('atom') do |f|
  f.channel.updated = Date.today.to_s

  # iterate through Ideas
  ideas[0,50].each do |r|
    f.items.new_item do |e|
      e.updated = DateTime.parse(r[:date].to_s).to_s
      e.title = r[:title]
      e.content.type = 'html'
    end
  end

  # iterate through Articles
  articles[0,50].each do |r|
    f.items.new_item do |e|
      e.updated = DateTime.parse(r[:date].to_s).to_s
      e.title = r[:title]
      e.content.type = 'html'
    end
  end
end
```

But the order of the items in the file is not sorted by date (because I loop through the first batch “Ideas” then ”Articles”)

I tried after iterating to sort by `date` / `updated` value, with the following combos:

```
  # f.items.sort {|a,b| a.updated <=> b.updated}
  # atom.items.sort! {|a,b| a.date <=> b.date}
  # f.items.reverse!
  # f.items.sort_by(&:date)
  # f.sort_by(&:date)
```

But without success.

Do I need to loop again through each item in the RSS to sort them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would combine both arrays into one `items` array and then sort that one before iterating over it:

```
atom = RSS::Maker.make('atom') do |f|
  f.channel.updated = Date.today.to_s

  items = ideas.first(50) + articles.first(50)
  items = items.sort_by { |item| item[:date] }

  # iterate through all items
  items.each do |r|
    f.items.new_item do |e|
      e.updated = DateTime.parse(r[:date].to_s).to_s
      e.title = r[:title]
      e.content.type = 'html'
    end
  end
end
```

Note that this works because both types (`articles` and `ideas`) have the same properties and are rendered into RSS in the same way.